# jquery, Showing a hidden item with a fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

in jquery, how can I show a hidden div, and make it fade in?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just hide the element initially, ether with [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or `style="display: none;"` (or `display: none;` in the stylesheet).  Then, just call [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), like this:

```
$("#elementID").fadeIn();
```

The [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) call automatically removes the `display: none` when it fades the opacity to 100%, it *won't* remove `visibility: hidden;` so don't use this, or you'll have to remove it manually.

Comment: Question: why hide it initially using `.hide()` rather than plain ol' CSS?

Comment: @dclowd9901 because if JavaScript is disabled then the element will be always visible instead of always invisible.

Comment: "I think sacrificing functionality for 99% of users to accommodate 1% is sheer bloody mindedness." -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/9478737/1066234

Comment: @KaiNoack it's more complex than that. JavaScript can also fail due to any error in either loading or the script itself. For example, a break in say a script loaded to have ads isn't something you'd want to hose the user experience.

Comment: @dclowd9901 -  *"why use the style sheet for styling?"*  I guess it was an old comment, maybe your answer's changed... 

Comment: Ha! 10 years is a very long time. As a now staff engineer, I hope nobody comes across this question/answer series 

Answer (score 2):

Use [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/):

```
$('#hiddendiv').fadeIn();
```

You may change the duration of the fadein:

```
$('#hiddendiv').fadeIn(1000); // 1000 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)**

```
$("selector").fadeIn();
```

> Display the matched elements by fading
>   them to opaque.

To hide it back anytime, you can use:

Note that you should initially hide it using css or jquery.

**[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("selector_for_your_div").fadeIn("slow");
```

For your edification, documentation for all of the bundled jQuery animation effects / tools is located at:
http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

**See:** [Jquery Documentation for `fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Answer (score 1):

Just an extra comment to Nick Craver perfect answer:

If you element already has a display attribute (e.g. display:block), do not substitute that with display:none. Instead, just add an extra display attribute. Just make sure to add display:none after (under) the other display attribute. When an attribute is repeated, the last value takes precedence.

```
.class {
   ...
   display:block;
   display:none;
}
```

Your element will be initially hidden (because of the second display attribute). As soon as fadeIn() starts it will remove display:none but will not touch the first display (display:block in my example). The first display attribute will then be used to style the class while it is fading and stay put after fadeIn() is done.

Answer (score 0):

`*selector*.fadeIn(*speed in miliseconds*)` is the function your looking for.

If you want the div to retain its space when its not seen use `style="opacity:0;"` instead of `display:none;`