# CSS transform not working in Internet Explorer 7 and below

Tags: html, css

I am using a CSS3 style-sheet to zoom images but it's not working in Internet Explorer 7 and below.

```
.resultitem{
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;

}
.resultitem:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
          transform: scale(1.3);
          display:block;
}
```

Comment: on which IE version its not working ?

Comment: Its not work on IE 7 and  lower

Comment: IE has only few version supporting released in last 2-3 years. else will not support

Comment: Even if IE8 without updates will not work

Comment: :) it is also not working in [Mosaic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(web_browser)) or any old enough browser... So far your question have just a statement...

Comment: CSS3 will not work till IE8, from 9 onward, you can have, and iE is having its own set of css classes, so you need to use them

Comment: Its possible to convert that css3 into css style code?

Answer (score 2):

IE9 supports CSS3 transformation with `-ms-trasform` but for older version there isn't any method but using a filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',
    M11=1.3, M12=0,
    M21=0, M22=1.3);
```

Where 1.3 is your scale factor.

M11, M12, M21 and M22 are values of the transformation matrix that will be applied to the element.

Note that this matrix will not scale the rectangle in the center. The best way to resolve this is to use some negative margins, minus half width times the factor for the left margin and minus half height times the factor for the top.

Links:
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Transformation Matrix](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

The transform property is not supported in any browser.

Internet Explorer(IE9+) supports an alternative, the -ms-transform property (2D transforms only).

Firefox supports an alternative, the -moz-transform property (2D transforms only).

Opera supports an alternative, the -o-transform property (2D transforms only).

Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the -webkit-transform property (3D and 2D transforms).

Comment: Old news... many browsers now support unprefixed `transform` property.

Comment: @web2008 Its possible to convert that code from css3 to css2?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If browser doesn't have support for any css3 selector then we can't provide that selector effect using css2.