# Internet Explorer background size issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to work around with the background size property in `IE 7` and `IE 8`. I know they don't support it and I am trying to use `AlphaImageLoader` for my solution. I want to change the image source dynamically in `javascript` but I am not sure how. Here are my codes.

```
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var imgSrc ='/images/' + image;

  div.className = 'div_element';
  div.style.width = '112px';
  div.style.height = '100px';
  div.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=imgSrc, sizingMethod='scale')";
```

The whole codes don't work. There is no images shown in IE. Are there anyways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142491/alternative-for-background-sizecover-in-ie7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this polyfill from Louis Remi](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) which affords IE versions background-size abilities.  It works wonders for me on my projects.  It's a simple .htc file (and maybe an .htaccess file, depending on your server configuration).

https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill