# Full width background image with proper aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm having an issue getting a full-width background image to retain its proper aspect ratio, and I've tried just about everything I could think of.

On the page I have an image with a CSS class called full-bg. (The reason I'm using an image is that the page is randomly calling the image from a Wordpress query with text that is then displayed on top of it, later in the page HTML.)

I'm using fairly standard CSS I've seen all over the place, but when you resize the browser to different widths, the background image is being skewed so the aspect ratio is no longer right.

Here is the image, and the CSS, any ideas what I can do?

```
<img class=​"full-bg active hide-for-small" src=​"/​wp-content/​uploads/​2013/​06/​Red.jpg">​

img.full-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
img.full-bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** 
I just realized one complication that may be causing issues. I'm using Foundation on the site, which automatically resizes images as the screen size shrinks. It normally resizes images to maintain their aspect ratio, but perhaps it's adding to the complexity of the issue?

Comment: Are your background images always landscape mode?

Comment: Yes, we're aiming to keep them landscape only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for background-size:cover in IE7+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142491/alternative-for-background-sizecover-in-ie7)

Comment: I'd suggest using backstretch.js http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `background-size: contain;` or `cover`, depending on what you need. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Note that if it's a background image, you should probably actually make it a `background-image` on a container.

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't supported on older browsers.

Comment: Perhaps I will just have to revisit that if nothing else works. I had attempted to switch to that format, but some other issues on the page made it difficult to change.

Comment: @Danrhul Not necessarily. You can achieve the same effect as `background-size: cover` in IE6-8 using AlphaImageLoader sizingMethod=scale.

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux That's not the same effect though is it? `Stretches or shrinks the image to fill the borders of the object.` I.e. Doesn't preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: Try it out in your browser. It scales the image, preserving the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
img.full-bg {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

for this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
li:first-of-type {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't really help, unfortunately. I'm also not clear why you have it as a list item for first-of-type?

Comment: You have your image inside an `<li>` tag, and the second image is moved by this `<li>` tag, and not by the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, it's not inside an LI tag. The image appears on the page a second time when it's used for the mobile display of the page (img class="mobile-image"). The background image appears a couple of lines above that (img class=​"full-bg active hide-for-small").

Comment: Look at the html code when you put your screen with less resolution.