# Building a Web-Based Facebook application using SPA / Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, facebook-canvas

i'm about to start building a new **Web-Based Facebook Application** (it's an entertainment application with more than 20 screens - it's large App).

My question is: 
Which is better using a **SPA framework** such as **Angular**? or building the Application using the straight forward web technique?

i mean by "straight forward web technique: every screen is in a separate page and navigation is done by links and passing URL parameters"

thanks in advance for your help, and i'd like to add the below notes to be considered in your answers

1. i'm working using PHP
2. i need a high performance application
3. i'm not an expert with Facebook App Reviews ... so please raise any concerns in this regard.

thanks a million

Comment: The SPA approach might start to bite you when it comes to sharing content on Facebook … you will need an individual URL for each individual piece of content that you want to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to read this awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages)
then you'll have to decide , and I also recommend you do a great research regarding the use of RESTful APIs , because this is what you'll be using instead of the traditional HTTP page requests.

**UPDATE**

After creating your RESTful API back-end you'll have to choose your framework for building SPA like `AngularJS` or `Backbone.js` or `knockout.js`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Angular is a way to go, especially for large web applications with many sites. It enables you to modularize and reuse your code, but definetly requires some learning.