# Better practice prepare html on backend or send data from backend to front end application

Tags: java, html, angularjs, web

I have a sport matches list for every day. My goal is print this list on the web page by url mysite.com/sport/year/month/day. All data about matches is saved in the database. I use Java Spring on server and AngularJS on web app. My question is which practice is better. Or prepare jsp file with html and send it when client do request or use AngularJS and get matches object from server by json format and then bind data to html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to are two different approaches to building a web application.

The first is considered a traditional client-server web application, while the second is a single-page application, also known as a SPA.

The are advantages and disadvantages listed for each approach. You should choose the approach based upon your requirements of the application you are building.

There are many links to these on the web. Here is one: [Single Page Application: advantages and disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages)

It should also be noted, that hybrids of both approaches are also valid and are very appropriate in many situations. This is where part of your application is a SPA, while the rest follows the traditional client-server architecture.

Analyse what's your requirements, and choose IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your response