# How to develop the UWP application with javascript without winjs support?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am developing the appllcaition based on given link with `javascript` and `html5`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-js-universal

But in this link they have used `WinJs` template to develop the application .But i want to develop the application without the `WinJs`  support. So can you please suggest to develop the application without the `WinJs` template.

Comment: very much possible

Comment: how is there any link for reference

Comment: This question as it stands is off topic. Please read the [help]. Specifically [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: i have edited my question is this ok??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But i want to develop the application without the WinJs support.

It is possible. WinJS is just a javascript library. You can use any js lib that you like to build your app, just like web development. But there are a few things you need to care about:

1. App Lifecycle: you will need to implement the app lifecycle events in your app，without WinJS, you can implement the lifecycle using below codes:

   ```
   Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", activatedEventhandler, false);
   Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("suspending", suspendingEventhandler, false);
   Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", resumingEventhandler, false);
   ```

   Here is a complete sample of App lifecycle:[Lifecycle Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-activating-and-ec15b168).
2. It is strongly recommended to make your app a Single Page Application. And here is a case that describes the [advantages and disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages).
3. For security reason, UWP doesn't support inline javascript. So something like this won't work: `<button onclick="someFunc()">Click Me</button>`

Comment: The first [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-activating-and-ec15b168) is invalid(thanks MS!). But the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130705021207/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-activating-and-ec15b168/view/SourceCode#content) still has it. Some general non-code info on the lifecycle [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-resume) too.