# back-end vs front-end controlled web application

Tags: php, angularjs, vue.js

I will explain first what I mean by "back-end controlled" and "front-end controlled".

I have been developing web applications for many years with php frameworks. It was always with the php back-end handling all the logic and also sending the "views" to the client. This is what I call a "back-end controlled web application".

Now I understand the advantage of separation of concerns of what I call a "front-end controlled application" where the back-end never sends the html views to the client. It only sends data and the view is completely handled by the client (angularjs, vuejs, ...). This allows the same back-end (which is now just a REST API) to be used also by a mobile application eventually.

So now I explained what I mean by "back-end controlled web application" and "front-end controlled web application" and explained that I understand some of the advantages of front-end controlled web applications. Now I will mention some of the doubts that I have regarding this, and I am expecting answers to these doubts because I am sure there are answers that I am just not aware of:

1. In a back-end controlled web application the forms are Cross-Site Request Forgery protected (at least when you use a decent back-end framework). Behind the scene a token is added to the session to confirm that the request comes from the same application form. How do you do that in a front-end controlled application?
2. I have seen front-end controlled applications making multiple requests for the same page (one request for authentication, and a request for each component (say section of the web page)). On the other hand we know that  it is a good practice to "browserify" our assets (css and js) to reduce the number of requests to the server. So, on one hand making as few requests to the back-end as possible is a good practice but on the other hand, with front-end controlled applications, It is very common to see a page that has 5 requests for example to the back-end. The same page would have needed only 1 request if it was a back-end controlled application.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry; what's the question? (Number 2 that is.)

Comment: You are confusing initial page load optimization with data requests. Also not hard to implement csrf with ajax

Comment: @Progrock, 1 and 2 are the questions/doubts about things that are not clear for me.

Comment: @charlieft, I understand page load of css and js different from loading json data, I am just wondering why in one case multiple requests are avoided and in the other case encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I researched again on csrf and IIUC, XHRs are better against csrf since:

   - modern browsers automatically add `origin` headers to all XHRs, which blocks all requests from unexpected domains (together with `allow-origin` config on server-side).
   - And we can do even more by manually adding csrf tokens to js code when rendering pages on server-side (to be sent with requests in XHRs later). The tokens inside js code are impossible for the attacker to acquire. **EDIT**: this is not unique for single-page apps, I've learned that traditional server-rendered sites can do the same by writing the token in a hidden field in a form after reading the `Synchronizer token pattern` chapter of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Rather than `<input type="hidden" name="csrftoken" value="..." />`, I thought of `<script>var csrfToken={{server.token()}}</script>` (`{{}}` is the server side template). The former is used when the form is posted, mine is used when js code sends XHRs. My idea is a mix of the `Synchronizer token pattern` chapter and its next in the wikipedia page. By these means, if our site is XSS free, the attacker won't be able to get the token in the session/page/js, and the request he tricks the user's browser to send will fail without the token.

     Which leads to: modern single-page apps are XHR *heavier* than traditional web apps, which utilizes full-page server-side render with js-manipulated view changes (with XHRs) on different occasions. And thus, more secure.
2. 1 request is definitely better than 5, if only for request counts' sake. Here we make the trade-off: By adding a few traffic to loading the page, we gain:

   - As OP addressed, server interfaces reusable by mobile apps since they return pure data rather than htmls which mix data with webpages.
   - Better separation of concerns for both front and back ends. Backend developer writes smaller single-functionality interfaces. And even better for frontend developer: views, styles, interaction logic scripts (as we can see in `.vue` files) are all organized in components, fewer things to worry about, happier we can be.

     Therefore I think the trade is totally worth it.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by sending csrf tokens from js to back-end when the page is rendered in server side? Any link explaining this?

Comment: @KarimMtl Edited that section. Also, your question may be essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages