# How is a single page application faster than a "normal" website?

Tags: caching, runtime, single-page-application, assets, browser-cache

My understanding is that a single page application (SPA) is faster because you're no longer navigating to new webpages whenever you click on links inside the app. As opposed to "normal" websites that have to 1.) make new requests for the shared assets and 2.) run/load those assets again each time you visit another page, a SPA will only request your shared assets once and only run them once if they remain on both the page you navigated from and the page you navigated to. Is this correct?

For example, if you have a website www.example.com and it has a page www.example.com/cats, even though both pages have the same cat asset and run the same jquery script, the browser will need to make the same 2 requests on each page visit to get the assets and then run the same 2 assets in order for each page to work. In contrast, the SPA version of this site will have the client only request and run the 2 assets once when it first visits and then keep those 2 assets running when it navigates to the cat page and then make additional requests and runs according to what new assets it needs that are specific to the cat page.

Answer (score 0):

That is not necessarily true. Browsers have variety of mechanisms that multiple page websites can utilize to increase performance.

Properly configured server will instruct browser to cache assets in HTTP cache. 
Some browsers implement BFCache and may cache and reuse pages without rerequesting assets and rerunning scripts. 
V8 Engine has a cache for compiled JavaScript source code.

For more information check resources below:

- [Single Page Application: advantages and disadvantages question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages)
- [HTTP Caching article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) by Ilya Grigorik
- [Do browsers parse javascript on every page load? question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096907/do-browsers-parse-javascript-on-every-page-load)
- [BFCache page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) on MDN