# pc and mobile site code using user agent

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make it for my site, 
This is my question:

If the user is using a computer to view my web page the css should be

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pc.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

But if they use mobile the css should be

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

How will I do it. I want html not php

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Use media queries, please.

Comment: Can you give me code to use

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this through media queries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" href="pc.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

If you wanted to go the Javascript route for this

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 1024) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/mobile.css");
    } else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/pc.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: You should really thank him by checking one as the correct answer.

Comment: If you have found this answer satisfied please click the check mark as an accepted answer. @ehis

Answer (score 0):

It may be more reliable do accomplish this with media queries in CSS. Because some browsers do not have JavaScript enabled, especially mobile browsers, it is considered a best practice to support basic functionality without JavaScript.  See [this answer by Haylem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492407/3337659) for more.

A great explanation of CSS3 media queries is available in [this SmashingMagazine.com article, "How to Use CSS3 Media Queries"](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/). In your example, you could quickly implement this as follows:

```
<style>
@import url(/pc.css) (min-width:480px);
@import url(/mobile.css) (max-width:480px);
</style>
```

Naturally this will not work in ancient versions of Internet Explorer, so you might need to consider this also:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/pc.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

However, if you do not have strong experience with responsive web design (RWD), you may be better off considering a CSS framework like Foundation or Bootstrap. Check out [this Mashable.com article for a good overview](http://mashable.com/2013/04/26/css-boilerplates-frameworks/).

You might also want to check out [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) which is used in the more comprehensive quick start kit, [INIT](http://use-init.com/).