# whether javascript libraries/framework like AngularJs, KnockJs will work if client side javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, knockout.js

There are many Javascript libraries/framework in the market.
I want to know whether these JS libraries/framework will work if the Javascript is disabled at client side?

My assumption is that it will not work.

If so, then what is the point of creating bigger applications using these JS libraries/framework, what would be the alternative when javascript is disabled at client end?

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative is to detect that JS is turned off and let the client know that their experience will be greatly downgraded because they refuse to support a web standard. In practice the percentage of people doing this is so small that unless you have some kind of weird requirement to support no JS its not even worth thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) to explain users that site is having issues because of disabled javascript.
And code like this for angularjs app

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <noscript>Please, enable javascript</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

according to this post of 2012 [Browser statistics on JavaScript disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478737/browser-statistics-on-javascript-disabled)
more than 97% of users use Javascript. Javascript improve the user experience, that's why it is important. You can also detect if user allowed javascript or not and provide them an alternative version if they don't.