# Insert Back Button in Form

Tags: php, html, forms

I feel like this is simple but i'm not sure where to start.

I have a multi-page form that the user clicks 'next' through to get onto the next page. I would like to also give them a 'back' button so that they can go back and change their response if they need to. How do I insert a 'back' button that still keeps their data on previous pages?

I don't need to track what their response was before or anything like that, just the final response is all that's necessary.

My form has a lot of code, so if you need to see another example please let me know:

Code at the very start of form:

```
    <form action="surveysubmit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Code to proceed to 'next' page and where I need the 'back' button:

```
<input class="submit-next" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="" />
```

Code to submit final page (and entire form):

```
<input class="submit-end" type="submit" name="submit_ninth" id="submit_ninth" value="" />
```

Comment: you can use sessions for this

Comment: Thank you, what is sessions? Sorry, probably silly question I know! Will try and Google it too.

Comment: ^ Realize what you mean by sessions now. Is this going to require a lot of recoding for my form though? I have most of it completed already so really don't want to have to go in and change everything.

Comment: then go with Saumil's answer then. I always work serverside which is a lot more reliable; but that's just "me" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If on clicking the "next" button the user is redirected to a new page each time then you can use `localStorage` to store the values which the user entered in the previous page,

For this edit the submit button in your each page as follows,

```
<input class="submit-next" onclick="saveValues()" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="" />
```

Your JavaScript code,

```
function saveValues(){
    //fetch all the form values
    var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;

    //Store it in the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("name", name);

   //Now submit the form
   document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Now on every page you have to check whether their are any set localStorage values,

```
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
    var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    document.geteElementById("inputName").value = name;
}
```

To display back button,

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if JS is disabled? serverside's much better and as a Plan-B. personally, I'd go with sessions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea serverside should be considered as Plan-B, but server side just doubles the work. According to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478737/browser-statistics-on-javascript-disabled about 99% of the browsers have JavaScript enables hence it is not much of a risk. Moreover, this is not a critical functionality which should be validated on server side. For Eg, You can't operate Facebook with all thee functionalities if JavaScript is disabled on your browser.

Comment: I'm part of the 1%ers who has JS disabled by default. Too many bad things can happen nowadays from unknown/untrusted sites. The ones I trust, I load the JS. I'm not saying that the OP can't be trusted, am just saying this in general.

Comment: doubling the work, well you know the saying: *"An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure."* - and it doesn't take much to do that and most sites have a Plan-B ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well if OP has the time then ofcourse he/she can implement the plan B. But my friend this is not a critical functionality like form validation so it is okay to neglect 1% of the population(sorry for you ;) ). One can always display a message using <noscript>...</noscript> tag to inform users if they want to experience all the functionalities of the website then enable JavaScript like Facebook and many other well established websites do.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When they go to the next page they are taken to a new page in terms of content, but the URL remains the same.

Comment: @IVCatalina I believe you can implement this solution even if the URL remains the same

Comment: Also, what type of coding do I use for the 'back' button itself?

Comment: @IVCatalina Do you want to display a button through which the user can visit previous page?

Comment: Yes, please! Ideally so.

Comment: When I click the button it just does the same as it does if I press the 'back' button, and takes me back to the previous URL I was on (i.e. out of the questionnaire entirely). Do I need to change anything in the code that you sent me - i.e. 'myForm' etc? Sorry, new to all this!

Comment: @IVCatalina I thought this is what you wanted, give me the HTML for entire questionnaire including all the forms

Comment: I want it to go back to the previous page of the multi-page form, not out of the questionnaire altogether.